# How could I scientifically explain the concept of "Stasis beams"?

Tags: science-fiction

(Note: I am WELL AWARE of the fact that I am asking for an explanation of an inherently unscientific concept. But the members of this particular Stack Exchange are so wonderfully intuitive and so ingenuitive I was hoping that you could answer a question among the lines of this).

Whilst many early Science Fiction franchises were more "pseudoscience" than actual "science" they DID in fact introduce a concept that I believe has been able to intrigue intuitive/scientifically analytical minds for years... Stasis Beams.

According to Wikipedia, Stasis Beams are: "confined areas of space in which time has been stopped or the contents have been rendered motionless"

Objects within a "Stasis Beam" are render (near) Indestructible.

My question is...

How could I scientifically explain Stasis Beams? (you can even take out the Indestructibility part if it conflicts with science)

Comment: It would help if you could give some parameters. Will this beam kill people if they are "frozen" in it? or is it supposed to keep people alive? is it going to be used as a weapon? what is it going to be? what does it need to do, what are it's requirements? I could give you many pseudoscience answers about random ways to implement a stasis beam - but it needs to work for your world/story.

Answer (score 4):

### Time Dilation

A German scientist studying some pretty abstract ideas figured out to solve this problem.
[You may have heard of him](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein).

From his work, we know that the most scientific way to explain slowing time is to [dilate it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation). Basically, if you move something fast enough, or subject it to incredibly strong gravity, it will experience time more slowly. You need incredible power to do either, and that needs explaining in itself, but it is somewhat realistic.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that if you have an hollow cylinder about 2 m tall and about 1 m wide with the mass of Jupiter, and you fit a person inside they would experience time 3 times slower.

Comment: ...and also die of course!

Comment: @SilverCookies, would they die instantly or take three times as long to die?

Comment: @EveryBitHelps I'm imagining instant death from the heat / pressure

Answer (score 2):

So lets examine this

You have a need to "freeze" something in time. Almost certainly a person - you eliminate the "indestructible" element as a mandatory criteria therefore you are not trying to bring undamaged through time some inanimate object.

You also are looking fo a stasis "beam" - looks like you are after some kind of possibly portable device/ weapon that can send a person into stasis unexpectedly and against their will.

I would have such a device be created probably with the use of some exotic mineral/ element.  I would have this arrive/ be discovered through either being on/in a meteor OR by being alien tech.  The alien tech is a bit of an easy cop-out in terms of science - because it doesn't really need to be explained.

On/In a meteor is a bit tougher - and therefore would take a bit of space in your story.  You will have to put in a bit of time describing the discovery of some new mineral/ element/ compound with unimaginable properties on a recent meteor. Somebody discovering it. Then having the smarts to do something with it - and then develop the device into some kind of portable "weapon".  This really only works well if you have a Tony Stark like figure to whip something up.

Effectively - I would have your science genius obtain the meteor and mess about with it a bit.  I would have them very quickly spot there is something odd about the material it is made of - then start in with some nondestructive tests. Probably some kind of X-Ray.  I would then have them notice something odd as a result.

The odd thing they would notice could simply be some strange fluorescing as they attempt to x-ray. And no exposure on the X-Ray film. They would then try other substances other than the X-Ray film - including bacteria on a petri dish. While it doesn't kill the bacteria - they notice it doesn't multiply either - which is a bit atypical for bacteria.  After some further experiments - they eventually decide to try it on a mouse.  BINGO - they find out they have created a stasis beam.  With a bit of work they figure out that one frequency causes stasis - and a different part of the spectrum causes stasis to be cancelled.

They would then turn the Meteor material into a lens - hook up some kind of portable x-ray generation and VOILA - you have your Stasis Beam.

An obvious risk would be sending only part of a person/ creature into stasis.  Another risk would be if somebody else was standing on the other side of your intended target.

One possible Scientific basis for this is it affects materials through an immediate stopping of ALL vibration/ energy usage - therefore essentially "freezing" the target in place.

Hopefully this gives you some simple & usable basis for developing this tech!

Comment: Why would you expect to find something in a meteor(ite) that’s not already found on Earth, when the Earth is made from zillions of those same bodies?

Comment: I think stopping *vibration* is an effect of freezing, not an explaination of how you are able to freeze things.

Comment: It's not necessarily a matter of expecting to find something - it's more a matter of a believable plot device to introduce something that can be used to construct the science the writer is wanting...

Comment: Vibration was perhaps not a great word choice. I've added energy usage which is maybe more useful.  Or maybe not... ;)

Comment: Not: you’re describing its *effect*, but labeled it as a *basis*.